# Gram-Schmidt to prove recurrence relation of orthonormal polynomials

Tags: numerical-methods

I have been told to apply Gram-Schmidt to $x\pi_k(x)$ to show that

$$
\pi_n(x)=(a_nx + b_n)\pi_{n-1}(x)+c_n\pi_{n-2}(x)
$$

with $n≥2$, $a_n$, $b_n$, and $c_n$ all constants that depend on $w(x)$.
for a family of orthonormal polynomials with respect to some weight function $w(x)$. I'm not exactly sure what that means.

Comment: What  $\pi_k,a_k,b_k,c_k,...$? Is there some inner product here?

Comment: This is the [recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials#Recurrence_relation) for orthonormal polynomials.